# What is another common phrase for I value something

Tags: phrase-request

What is other common phrases for "I value "something""?

"Something" can refer to anything.

For example, one can be I appreciate your effort.

Comment: to prize something, to appreciate, to love, to esteem, to evaluate ... depends all on context

Comment: Hi Victor. You may want to take a look at the ["Details, please" thread on meta](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/439/). I notice that many of your questions haven't been well received, and I think if you added more explanation of why you're asking and what you've done to try to answer the question yourself, you might see a few more up-votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many phrases that we can use with "I value", but it is not possible to state how common each one is. Some examples:

- I value life
- I value the quality of life
- I value our friendship
- I value the time we spent together

As mentioned by Hector, the meaning of each of these places importance and/or appreciation on the object being discussed.